# How to select dynamic range(from active selection) of data source for pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

Help me Take Source data for my pivot table from selection

```
Sheets("Filtered Data").Select
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Here my Selection process ends and pivot table selects data, can you help me making it dynamic?

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Filtered Data!R1C1:R21C8", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Snap!R6C6", TableName:="PivotTable13", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

Formatting the pivot data Stuff down there not so important

```
Sheets("Snap").Select
Cells(6, 6).Select
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").PivotFields("CMP")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").PivotFields("Area")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable13").PivotFields("Site Name"), "Count of Site Name", xlCount
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
Columns("F:K").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:= Sheets("Filtered Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Snap!R6C6", TableName:="PivotTable13", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion15
```

Comment: It worked like charm, tested for all the other errors works flawless, Thank you so much.